# Horizontal UIStackView Expanding Vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I've got a few nested UIStackViews as seen below:

[image: Screenshot]

What I'm trying to achieve is, to have the bottom-right label expand and grow vertically as a multi-line UILabel. I've already set the following properties for it:

- Lines: 0
- Line Break: Word Wrap

However, the UILabel is still not expanding vertically as expected. Some other SO answers have said to set a fixed width for the UILabel, but as the parent view could stretch in width, I'm not sure how well that would work out in the end.

Does anyone have a solution for this?